# If <td> has the largest int, in its <tr> add css class to <td> - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a table of data, and I'm trying to at a glance look over it and find the highest number on each row.

To do this I'm adding a css class called highest to the highest `<td>` like this

```
  <tr>
      <td>4.2</td>
      <td class="highest">5.0</td>
      <td>2.9</td>
  </tr>
```

with this css

```
td.highest {font-weight:bold;}
```

But this is all hardcoded, I'm trying to work out how to write this using jquery, but I'm pretty new to js and not really sure were to start, I was looking at using `Math.max` but as I can tell thats to be used on arrays, rather that reading html, any ideas ?

I've made a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/pudle/vEUUQ/

Comment: What is the source of the data? An SQL query and a server side language?

Comment: 4.2 and 2.9 are not `int` values

Comment: mysql / php, i get the data from a mysql query, then a i get an array from which i generate the table

Comment: is it possible for two cells to have the same (highest) value?

Comment: @alnitak, yes there could be two of the same value

Comment: @sam thought so - that's why my answer sets every matching cell, and doesn't assume only one.  It does make the code slightly more expensive though as you have to loop through the elements twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First bash - shorter (and potentially more efficient) answers may be available...

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $td = $(this).children();

    // find all the values
    var vals = $td.map(function() {
        return +$(this).text();
    }).get();

    // then find their maximum
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, vals);

    // tag any cell matching the max value
    $td.filter(function() {
        return +$(this).text() === max;
    }).addClass('highest');
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/DggUN/

Comment: @sam I made a better version of the final loop

Answer (score 1):

Based upon this structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>4.2</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>2.9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use JS/jQuery and do:

```
var highest = 0;

$("table tr td").each(function() {
     var current = $(this).text();
    if (current > highest) {
       highest = current;
       $(".highest").removeClass();
       $(this).addClass('highest');   
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syU82/

Comment: this is wrong - it finds the highest value in the whole table, not per row/.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing I can think of is to use http://underscorejs.org/#max or http://lodash.com/docs#max and pass in a function that filters for this.

```
var result = _.max($("td"),function(td){ return parseFloat($(td).text()); });
result.addClass("highest");
```

Otherwise you can do it the long way:

```
var result,max 0;
$("td").filter(function(){
   var myval = parseFloat($(this).text());
   if(myval > max){
      result = this;
      max = myval;
   }
});
result.addClass("highest");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, not as good as some of the others though.

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $highest_el;
    var highest_num;

    $('td', this).each(function() {
        if ( $highest_el === undefined || parseFloat($(this).text()) > highest_num ) {
            $highest_el = $(this);
            highest_num = $(this).text();
        }
    });

    $highest_el.addClass('highest');
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hRJLQ/2/